# Doing hourly rate calculations for hour more than 24

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am recording my time spent on a project in google excel sheet. There is a column which does addition of the recorded time and output total time to column say `D40`. The output time looks like `<hoursspent>:<minutesspent>:<secondsspend>`. For example `30:30:50` would mean that i have worked for *30* hours and *30* minutes and *50* seconds on a project.

Now, I was using this formula to calculate my total invoice

`=(C41*HOUR(D40))+(C41*((Minute(D40)/60)))+(C41*((SECOND(D40)/3600)))`

Where `C41` cell contains my *hourly rate* (say $50).

This is working fine as long as the numbers of hours that i have worked are less than *24*. The moment my numer of hours go above *24*. The `Hour` function return the modulus value i.e., `HOUR(30)` would return `6`.

How can I make this calculation generic in a way that it oculd calculate on more than 24 hours value too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=C41*D40*24
```

and change formet on the result as $
[image]

one hour is part of a day, as you know 1/24th of a day, that's why you could multiply by 24 to get hours, and then multiply it by the rate

Comment: it works but i am not sure if i understand the solution here :s why multiply by 24. I have already setup the format of `D40` column as duration and `C4` & `result` column as currency. Adding time to duration is giving accurate result.

Comment: whatever the format, the value consists of an integer part equal to the number of days and a decimal part equal to the number of hours divided by 24 (because 24 hours = 1 day). By multiplying everything by 24 we obtain a number of hours in numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace HOUR(D40) with INT(D40)*24+HOUR(D40)

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(D40,":"),{C41,C41/60,C41/3600})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you store a value as HH:mm:ss into an Excel sheet, it automatically formats it as a Time, so it makes sense that HOUR modulos by 24.

Which is why you can simply ignore it. If you have a cell that is formatted as currency (FORMAT > Math > Currency) or any other normal Number-like format, then you can see, if you perform a numerical operation like multiplication, that it stores times like "30:30:50" as if it were a TIMEVALUE with a value over 1. Simply multiply that by 24, and then by your hourly rate, and you'll get your value, i.e,

`=D40 * C41 * 24` :

[image: an example spreadsheet with the values from the question]